# how to read content of contentEditable div?

Tags: elm

I use a [contentEditable](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_contenteditable) div, and I want to access its content after the user has modified it (onBlur).  How can I access the innerHtml or textContent of the DOM element ?  Any idea ?

Here is a simple example :

```
import Html exposing (div, text)
import Html.App exposing (beginnerProgram)
import Html.Events exposing (onBlur)
import Html.Attributes exposing (contenteditable)


main =
  beginnerProgram { model = "Hello", view = view, update = update }


view model =
  div [contenteditable True, onBlur (SaveInput)] [ text model ]


type Msg = SaveInput


update msg model =
  case msg of
    SaveInput ->
      "ok"
```

I wish to replace "ok" with a formula using [textContent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp) to get the value entered by the user. I am using elm v 0.17.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.
You'll have to extract the value from the event object using Json.Decode.

```elm
import Html exposing (Html, div, text)
import Html.App exposing (beginnerProgram)
import Html.Events exposing (onBlur, on)
import Html.Attributes exposing (contenteditable, id)
import Json.Decode as Json
import Debug

main : Program Never
main = beginnerProgram { model = "Hello" , view = view , update = update }

type alias Model = String

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div [ contenteditable True ,on "blur" (Json.map SaveInput     targetTextContent)]
    [ text model ]

targetTextContent : Json.Decoder String
targetTextContent =
  Json.at ["target", "textContent"] Json.string

type Msg = SaveInput String

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    SaveInput str -> (Debug.log "saving" str)
```

Comment: Thanks @tosh for the tip on `Debug.log`. I needed that :)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't give access to any new lines in the content. I think?

Answer (score 0):

I combined Tosh's answer with a little extra user help by using `Dom.focus` so that after clicking on the element to edit, the cursor became properly visible.

```
update ... = 
        EditTitle ->
            ( model | editTitle = True }
            , Dom.focus "view-title" |> Task.attempt FocusResult
            )



viewNameEditor : Model -> Html Msg
viewNameEditor m =
    let
        attrs =
            if m.editTitle then
                    [ contenteditable True
                    , on "blur" (Json.map SaveViewName targetTextContent)
                    , id "view-title"
                    ]

            else
                    [ contenteditable False
                    , onClick EditTitle
                    , id "view-title"
                    ]
    in
        div attrs [ text current.name ]
```